# How to filter/hook-into retrieve_password() to filter $_POST['user_login']?

Tags: php, password

I'm developing a website where the username is a document number, called CPF (think of it as a national ID), which has the following mask:

```
000.000.000-00
```

I'm storing the usernames as plain numbers, but all our forms must have the mask above, which in turn makes it so the `_POST['user_login']` always goes with the dash and dots. This is an example of a user's login/username:

```
$_POST['user_login']  = '123.456.789-00'
$actual_username_ondb = '12345678900'
```

This wasn't a problem for logging in, as I hook into the [wp_authenticate](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate) action hook *(not the pluggable function!)* and I filter the username before continuing (and also check if the number is a valid CPF):

```
/**
 * Hooks before login and filters out the CPF mask if it exists
 */
add_action( 'wp_authenticate' , 'filter_username' );
function filter_username(&$username) {
    $cpf = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/is', '', $username);
    if (is_valid_cpf($cpf)) {
        $username = $cpf;
    }
}
```

However, now I'm dealing with the lost password form, and I couldn't find any way to do the same as above, i.e.: filter `$_POST['user_login']` before going on with the password retrieval.

If there's any way to do it, it'd be via the hook `lostpassword_post`, because that's the earliest hook in the [retrieve_password()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/retrieve_password/) function, but unfortunately it only triggers after the data is already parsed, so I don't know how it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that could work for you?

```
/**
* Hooks before login and filters out the CPF mask if it exists
*/
add_action( 'wp_authenticate' , 'somos_filter_username' );
function somos_filter_username() {
  $cpf = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/is', '', $_POST['user_login']);
  if (is_valid_cpf($cpf)) {
    return $cpf;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, the action `wp_authenticate` is not called in when retrieving a lost password, otherwise it'd have worked out-of-the-box, since the login form already has the filter in place.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this hook.

```
function filter_retrieve_password_message( $title, $user_login, $user_data ) { 
    $cpf = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/is', '', $user_login);
    if (is_valid_cpf($cpf)) {
       $user_login = $cpf;
    }       
    return $title; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_title', 'filter_retrieve_password_message', 10, 4 );
```

http://hookr.io/filters/retrieve_password_title/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This hooks much later on the retrieve_password() function. Also, the password reset e-mail has nothing to do with the issue, the function fails much earlier, as there's no user named `123.456.789-00` on the database, only `12345678900`, so the function returns a WP_Error at line 337 of wp-login.php and it doesn't execute the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be  to change the username via JavaScript, before the user send the lost password form.

```
function my_test_func()
{
    // load the script only on the lost password page
    if( array_key_exists('action', $_GET) AND $_GET['action'] == 'lostpassword' ):
?>  

<script type="text/javascript">

    // bind the function on the submit prozess
    document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function(e) {

        // get the value from the input field
        var value = document.getElementById('user_login').value;

        //replace the first dot
        value = value.replace('.', '');

        //replace the second dot
        value = value.replace('.', '');

        //replace the dash
        value = value.replace('-', '');

        // write the value back in the input field
        document.getElementById('user_login').value = value;
    }

</script>

<?php
  endif;
}

add_action('login_footer', 'my_test_func');
```

The user enters his username and hit the button "Get New Password"

[image: Wordpress Login Page with the unformatted username]

The JavaScript change the username and the form will submit.
[image: Wordpress Login Page with the formatted username]

Comment: Yeah! That's actually *exactly* what I'm doing, since apparently there's no other way around it. Though a workaround, it works quite well. Thanks for the detailed answer by the way, your implementation was quite better than mine :D